# Excel to R, value changes when importing with readxl

Tags: r, excel, readxl, writexl

I am quite new to R. I need to work with a number of lists that I have in excel, but when importing them with `readxl` the numbers seem to be changing.

I have a spreadsheet (example [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9o1pz63pzh39ve/A%20Matrix%20-%20Table%205%202019-20.xlsx?dl=0)), and when I subtract the sum of the tab "target_intputs" to the sum of the tab "target_outputs" in excel, the total is 0 (as it should be, see "comparison" tab). However, after importing it to R, if I compare them using `print(sum(target_inputs) - sum(target_outputs))`, it gives me 6.007031e-08 as the total.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
library(readxl)
target_inputs <- read_excel("C:\\A Matrix - Table 5 2019-20.xlsx", sheet="target_inputs")
target_outputs <- read_excel("C:\\A Matrix - Table 5 2019-20.xlsx", sheet="target_outputs")

target_inputs <- as.numeric(target_inputs)
target_outputs <- as.numeric(target_outputs)

print(sum(target_inputs) - sum(target_outputs))
```

I assumed there could be a problem with the decimal points, so I tried the `round()` function and `options(digits=20)`, etc., but I cannot get rid of the problem. This seems to be happening only in R, as when I export it back again using the code below, the problem seems to disappear.

```
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(target_inputs, "C:\\target_inputs.xlsx")
write_xlsx(target_outputs, "C:\\target_outputs.xlsx")
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

---- EDIT 1 ----
This happens with some datasets, others don't give me the problem.

---- EDIT 2 ----
I just noticed that if I increase the decimal points with `options(digits=22)` I can see changes in the decimal points of the values. For example, in excel the first value of "target_inputs" is **23923.72846564920000000**, and after importing to R `target_inputs[[1]]` gives me **23923.72846564929932356**. But then, exporting it back to xlsx gets the values back to the original... I don't get what I could be doing wrong

Comment: sidenote: ```read_excel```  has an argument to make all loaded in information numeric ```col_types = "numeric"```, maybe it helps to read the excel files in as numeric?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. After realising that the decimal points were changing I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127910/r-changing-excel-values-during-importing-with-read-excel). Seems to be related to the floating-point precision. The solution (at least for me) is to round and adjust the numbers in excel before importing them to R. Cheers